# get image ids that not have any running container in docker cli

Tags: bash, docker, docker-cli

Is it possible to output the **list of image ids that the container is not currently running?**
This command prints the id list of all the images in the output, but I only want the images that do not have an active container.

```
docker images -q
```

Finally, **I want to remove the images that do not have an active container**
delete HDD so that the limited space of the server is not full.
Currently, I am using this command `docker rmi $(docker images -q)`, because some of the images have an active container, an error is encountered and the cd job fails.
**If you know of a bash script that can help, add it.**

Comment: Sooo just `docker system prune`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a docker command that deletes images that do not have an associated running container:

- `docker image prune`
  allows you to clean up dangling images (a dangling image is not tagged and not referenced by any container)
- `docker image prune -a`
  will remove all images that are not used by any existing containers
- `docker image prune -a --filter "until=48h"`
  you can add a filter (--filter) to limit the images to be pruned, as in this example, only images that are older than 48 hours

You can add the `-f` or `--force` flag to prune the images and not prompt for confirmation

You could use this in a scheduled bash script to keep your drive tidy

Comment: thanks, I run this command in a GithubAction workflow job and don't know how to pass 'y' when docker asks 'are you sure to ...'!

Comment: Updated the answer above to include the ```-f``` flag